# Select Case Query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.5

```
SELECT  * CASE WHEN (Employees.End_Date is null) THEN 
select  EmpId, Emp_Name, Salary , Start_date , End_date ,
DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(Start_Date, INTERVAL 30 DAY), Start_Date) * Salary/30 as 'Total_Salary'
    from  Employees ELSE 
Select  EmpId, Emp_Name, Salary , Start_date , End_date ,
DATEDIFF(End_Date, Start_Date) * Salary/30 as 'Total_Salary'
    from  Employees END
    From  Employees;
```

Please Help me out to find the syntax error in the above query. I am new to MySql so Please Help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like ...

```
select
  EmpId
, Emp_Name
, Salary 
, Start_date 
, End_date   
, case
    when end_date is null then
      DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD(Start_Date, INTERVAL 30 DAY), Start_Date ) * Salary/30 
    else 
      DATEDIFF(End_Date, Start_Date) * Salary/30 
  end as 'Total_Salary'
from employees;
```

The column with the `CASE` expression can be simplified to:

```
DATEDIFF(COALESCE(end_date, 
    DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY), start_date) * salary / 30 AS Total_Salary
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * CASE ...
```

-->

```
SELECT *, CASE ...
```

Subqueries need parens:

```
... THEN SELECT ...
```

-->

```
... THEN ( SELECT ... )
```

You can't have a subquery in a CASE delivering more than one column of one row.

(There may be more errors.)